# Handling a Refactoring Project with Limited Access to Source Code

Tags: web-development, security, refactoring, interview, source-code

I recently finished an interview with a company as a web developer. I'm the first and only developer that is about to be hired in this company.

They have a web application that was created by a software company, and they have received the source code of the app.

Years went by, and now they want to refactor their web app, but this time by hiring a full time web developer that takes responsibility of anything regarding the web app.

I just finished the interview and everything went perfect! but here comes the problem ..

They wanted to test my refactoring ability, so they gave me a couple of tasks to refactor. I said that's great, send me a copy of the source code and I'll refactor the web app locally and show you all the updates I can make. but they refused for security reasons, they seem to be afraid that I might steal, hijack, or attack the web app in any shape or form by having a copy of the source code.

They instead wanted me to do a live refactor during an online call by accessing the IT admin's screen using a software and accessing the C panel from his computer and modify the code live inside the C panel.

It was pretty difficult, I explained to the IT admin that this is difficult for a variety of reasons:

1- I'm completely new to the code base, I need sometime to understand what's going on with the code and study it good.

2- Refactoring inside the C panel is difficult, I need a code editor like Visual Studio Code to easily navigate through the project and better understand what is going on.

But unfortunately, he refused, saying that he can't share the source code to a stranger, as I haven't signed a job agreement yet.

I explained to him that it's perfectly normal to share a "COPY" of the source code for a potential hire, as any modifications will only reflect in my local machine, and not the hosted app, they are two separate instances.

I'm feeling a bit overwhelmed and I'm not sure how to proceed, so I posted this question here to learn from you experts and those who had a similar experience.

Comment: You have some legal and work environment constraints outside the scope of what this community typically deals with. [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be a better community, however your question is also very technical. If you post it at The Workplace, make sure it focuses on how to handle this interview situation rather than how to use a coding tool or how to write code.

Comment: Honestly, I'd just skip this company. This kind of exercise on actual prod code has no place in an interview. And it's misguided anyways, as you have pointed out. Refactoring also requires tools to perform properly.

Comment: @Ccm: I somewhat sympathize with the company here, assuming that they genuinely had no need for an ongoing development team until right now. They simply lack the expertise to handcraft exercises, they barely understand any of the "magic mumbo jumbo", so it makes sense for them to instead bring their own car to the mechanic and see if the mechanic is any good. Sure, a company with an established development department would better avoid this; but this is a specific case. Note that if the company hugely undervalued its need for ongoing development, the consequences of that would be on their head

Answer (score 6):

For the purpose of actually refactoring the code, this is not a good setup. Legalities/ethics of having done so without pay aside, I still would not even consider committing any of your changes, as you clearly were not well-informed at the time of making them.

However, as an interview exercise where people are judging your abilities, a live exercise is not unreasonable by itself.

> 2- Refactoring inside the C panel is difficult, I need a code editor like Visual Studio Code to easily navigate through the project and better understand what is going on.

Anything I say here is influenced by just how prohibitively unreadable the source code was; but I would argue that it was a bad call to argue that you *need* an IDE. Sure, it makes things easier, but the goal is not for you to fully peruse the codebase or make perfect improvements, it's to display your abilities as a developer.

> 1- I'm completely new to the code base, I need sometime to understand what's going on with the code and study it good.

You've lost track of what the goal of the exercise is. The goal is not to make an improvement that is ripe for merging into the codebase. The goal is to showcase that you have the necessary skills to make these kinds of improvements once you're employed.

What an interviewer would be looking for would be more related to what you're thinking and how you're trying to approach it, rather than what you write or what file you open.

As an interviewer, I would read between the lines here and infer that you're likely to lose track of goals by fixating on other things. This is just an educated guess, not a proven fact about you, but this is how interview exercises work.
In a company where you'd be a one man department and there'd be no one with the technical expertise to rectify your mistakes or scope creep; this is a point of concern, and it makes you a less favorable applicant (if there were others).

> I explained to him that it's perfectly normal to share a "COPY" of the source code for a potential hire, as any modifications will only reflect in my local machine, and not the hosted app, they are two separate instances.

You've missed the mark here.

Their concern isn't that you can somehow alter their live website, it that they would be giving you an entire solution that is their property, and nothing is preventing you from taking this code and doing something else with it, maybe even selling it to a competitor.
If you are aware of the concept of digital piracy, then *"perfectly normal to share a "COPY" of [digital asset]"* should not have come across as a harmless statement to you.

If anything, your response here would negatively impact my assessment of you as a technical applicant, especially in a company where you will be a one man department and there's likely not going to be a second line of defense for technical mistakes.

To be perfectly frank, I have rejected dozens of applicants who met all of the vacancy's criteria but during the interview would show their current employer's source code when showcasing their knowledge/skills/experience, even if they only shared their screen and showed a handful of files. **You simply do not share private code**, and this is a significant no-no from anyone with a sense of security.

Providing a digital copy of the entire codebase is several orders of magnitude worse than that. Asking for it, and then persisting after having been told no already, is a very concerning behavior on your end.

> they seem to be afraid that I might steal, hijack, or attack the web app in any shape or form by having a copy of the source code.

I want to reiterate on this point, because you state here that they explicitly claimed that it had to do with their live website, and my above feedback assumes that you misinterpreted this.

*Even if* that's what they believe and *even if* that was the *only* concern they had, and they had no concerns regarding the spreading of their proprietary product source code; then it was still the wrong call to argue with them and insist after already having been told no.

It's okay to try and redirect things, but it needs to be a cooperative effort. If it's a yes/no back and forth, that's an unproductive attitude and it does not reflect well on you as an applicant.

*Even if you were correct* (which in my opinion you weren't) and they were wrong, it still means that you and this company are not going to find a common productive ground.

I'm still not convinced that this was their (only) concern though.

> But unfortunately, he refused, saying that he can't share the source code to a stranger, as I haven't signed a job agreement yet.

It's not unheard of to sign an NDA at this stage for the company to feel more secure in revealing its code.

To be fair, from the POV of the company I understand not wanting to reveal their source code as a point of principle. Even though I also acknowledge that the odds of them being impacted negatively are exceedingly small, that doesn't matter; an unnecessary risk should not be taken just because you think the odds of it going wrong are low.

However, the subsequent advice is that an interview exercise should then be held using an example that is hand-crafted by the interviewers (or their peers) in order to judge particular skills that they're looking for in an applicant.
Based on this company not having any developers, this is obviously not possible, and I'm genuinely happy to see that they did not just copy/paste some regurgitated "developer interview questions" because these are not great indicators of developer skill.

This is where I would advise the company, if they were the ones posting the question here, to reach out to a recruitment agency. This is *precisely* their core focus: providing skilled interview ability (often relating to the nuts and bolts of the vacant position) when the company lacks either the manpower or knowledge to properly assess its applicants.

Alternatively, they could hire a freelancer to design an interview exercise and give them the basic rundown on what improvements to expect - but I would only expect this shortcut to work for a junior vacancy where the goals are simple and easily confirmed by laymen. I wouldn't trust this process when assessing applicants for a senior role.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a [refactoring](https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html). With no access to source, no tests, and nothing indicating the point of the refactor, what you’re really doing is called [reverse engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering).

Rather than worry about how it actually works just reproduce the effect you can see. Sure that may mean you’re talking to an imagined API rather than a real one but remember, this is a show. It just has to look impressive.

Now personally, I’d never evaluate you this way. But, much like asking interviewees “why is a manhole cover round?” the answer isn’t important. It’s just an excuse to get you talking. All you really need to do is sound like someone they can work with.

As for their security paranoia, remember you said they have no current developers. So of course they have no idea what they can safely share. Cut them a little slack.

And while it may be that the code shouldn’t contain secrets that doesn’t mean it doesn’t. Passwords leak on GitHub all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to persuade them its a bad idea.

Turning them down, or debating is turning the job down.

Say you are concerned about editing a live website and protect yourself by asking them to sign a waiver

1. You are not to be held responsible for any damage caused.
2. They won't use any of your work without payment
3. You are fully authorised to see anything they show you and access their systems for the purpose of the interview/demonstration

If they sign, just go for it and hope for the best. You can prob make a copy of whatever page they choose, rename it and demo on that and everyone will be happy.

Asking for a wavier, which can just be them agreeing in a email, shows you are serious and professional